# Secure all resources(images, scripts, pages, sessionCookie) with https ASP.NET MVC web-site and also redirect from http to https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-7, https

I would like to know how to redirect from `**http**` to `**https**` but keep all the resources in safety.

I know IIS' `Require SSL` protect all resources of the site. But what about redirecting? If I use `URL Rewrite` module, I have to disable Require SSL option on `IIS`. Can I teach my site to redirect from `http` to `https` but also secure all the resources?

And yes, I must protect all the resources of my web-site. Web-site will be over only by https.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could consider would be to have 2 websites, one for normal page requests and the other for resources.

Your resource website would only support `https`, and it wouldn't need to handle redirects.

Your main website would serve both `http` and `https`, and issue redirects from `http` -> `https` using whatever method you wished, be the `URL Rewrite` module or MVC's `[RequireHttps]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I'll analyze your solution. And also my web-site will be over only by https.

Comment: I only meant handle http insofar as to issue a redirect to https.